# Is there a decentralized zk-SNARK (zero-knowledge Succinct Non-Interactive ARgument of Knowledge)?

Tags: decentralization, zksnark, trust, zero-knowledge

Normally, in `zk-SNARK`, we need to generate two public keys: one for `prover` and one for `verifier`. However, the input parameter of this generator algorithm must be secret, meaning that it must be hidden for both `prover` and `verifier`.

And because of this, the process of those public generation is done by a **trusted third party**.

Since using a **trusted third party** is **not desirable** for **decentralized** blockchain, I am looking for a **decentralized** approach of those public key generation. Is there ? or it's impossible to have a **decentralized** `zk-SNARK` ?

**P.S.** More information about `zk-SNARK` is found here: https://media.consensys.net/introduction-to-zksnarks-with-examples-3283b554fc3b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the verification key can be computed using multiparty computation (MPC). In this setup, `n` people participate in the construction and each independently and randomly generate the secret input. The system is set up such that so long as at least one of the participants discards their secret then the resulting keys are secure.

You can find details about the original ZCash key generation "ceremony" here:

- [MPC protocol whitepaper](https://github.com/zcash/mpc/blob/master/whitepaper.pdf)
- [ZCash Paramater Generation Overview](https://z.cash/technology/paramgen.html)
- [New MPC Protocol for ZCash Sapling](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1050)

Comment: Thank you, Is this approach used only for `verification key` (key used by verifier) ? or for **both** `proving key` (key used by prover) and `verification key` ? Thanks

Comment: Btw your second link: (ZCash Paramater Generation Overview) does not work (`The webpage at https://z.cash/technology/paramgen.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"`). Thanks

Comment: The proving key doesn't need anything secret, so it doesn't really apply. The link works for me

Answer (score 3):

You also might want to check out the following resources.

The ING blockchain team has submitted their proposal for efficient ZKP's to ethereum. It's not a SNARK but a range proof.

https://github.com/ing-bank/zkrangeproof

There is also Zokrates but it's 10x more expensive.

https://github.com/JacobEberhardt/ZoKrates

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by "expensive" ? Do you mean "time complexity" ? `Zokrates` is apparently an Ethereum toolbox for `zk-SNARK`.

Comment: The ING system doesn't work on the public blockchain. It would require a hard fork to implement.

Comment: I Mean expensive as in gast cost for the verification contract. The ING contract costs 3 Million gas for verification.  The Zokrates implementation costs about 30 million gas. 

@Tjaden, Are you sure , It's based on byzantium precompiles so it should work on main net.

Comment: Oh, you're right they updated it apparently. Older versions predate byzantium. Of course, range proofs are strictly less expressive than SNARKs

Comment: @NicoVergauwen really? given the current 8 million gas limit, how could the verification cost 30 million gas? i

Comment: My bad , ZKRP 180k gas , ZK-SNARK 1.6 mil gas

Comment: in a private network you can increase the blockgas limit so it wouldnt be an issue

Comment: True, but you would also have less of a need for ZKRP in a private network.

Comment: The AZTEC protocol which allows to do ZK transfers with any token is based on ZKRP https://www.aztecprotocol.com/

Answer (score 1):

ZK-STARKs are addressing the issue of the trusted setup in ZK-SNARKs. There is a blog post from Vitalik on this topic:

https://vitalik.ca/general/2017/11/09/starks_part_1.html

> Hopefully many people by now have heard of ZK-SNARKs, the general-purpose succinct zero knowledge proof technology that can be used for all sorts of usecases ranging from verifiable computation to privacy-preserving cryptocurrency. What you might not know is that ZK-SNARKs have a newer, shinier cousin: ZK-STARKs. With the T standing for “transparent”, ZK-STARKs resolve one of the primary weaknesses of ZK-SNARKs, its reliance on a “trusted setup”. They also come with much simpler cryptographic assumptions, avoiding the need for elliptic curves, pairings and the knowledge-of-exponent assumption and instead relying purely on hashes and information theory; this also means that they are secure even against attackers with quantum computers.